# Percentile_cont / Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, plsqldeveloper

I am using `percentile_cont` to find the percentile of a distribution. My table is:

```
Class_id    RollNum Marks 
1             1        10
1             2        12
1             3        16
1             4        08
1             5        17
```

I am using the query

```
SELECT class_id, 
       percentile_cont(0.05) within group (order by marks) as marksPerntl 
  from myTable group by class_id
```

Now, is it possible to also query the roll number which got the percentile?

Comment: Given the table data you posted, your query doesn't run - it fails with `ORA-00937: not a single-group group function : SELECT class_id, percentile_cont(0.05) within group (order by marks) as marksPerntl from myTable`.  [SQLFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/cdfbf/1).  Please edit your question and either correct the data, post working code, or add additional explanation.  Thanks.

Comment: hi there was a group by syntax missing. I have edited the question now. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The [`PERCENTILE_CONT`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions110.htm) function interpolates values, giving you the value of `Marks` which would fall into the 5% percentile in your distribution.

Running your query with the above data will return ([SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/cdfbf/7) from @Bob Jarvis's comment):

```
| CLASS_ID | MARKSPERNTL |
--------------------------
|        1 |         8.4 |
```

Your data set does not contain any rows where `Marks` is `8.4`. Therefore, there isn't a single `RollNum` value which got the percentile.